# Default values for attributes not available in theme

Tags: android

I have defined custom attribute to use in my views:

```
<attr name="customColor" format="color"/>
```

And specified its value in my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- some other values -->
    <item name="customColor">#6d4c41</item>
</style>
```

Now, I can use this attribute value in my view. Both in XML:

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="?attr/customColor"
/>
```

and in code (Kotlin):

```
with(
    context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
        intArrayOf(R.attr.customColor)
    )
) {
    textColor = getColor(0, Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
    recycle()
}
```

(Java):

```
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        new int[]{R.attr.customColor}
);
textColor = a.getColor(0, Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
a.recycle();
```

In case I **forget to define** the value in my theme, the code above will work fine, since I specified the default value. However, the XML will throw an exception when I try to inflate it.

Is there a way to specify default attribute value for XML?

Comment: Nope, I really don't think you can, at least not in any way I can think of. The only places in resources that you can set values for attributes are in styles and themes, and there isn't really such a thing as an overall default theme for an app, apart from what you specify on the `<application>` tag. If you don't set that, a device default will be used, and that certainly won't have your custom attribute in it.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Although unfortunate, this is exactly the conclusion I reached myself.